# Как изменить переменную в php-файле

Tags: php

Есть php-файл примерно с таким содержимым

```
define('TME_ID', 15);
define('THEME', 'auto');
define('TEMPLATE', 'audi');
```

В другом скрипте во время работы необходимо прочитать этот файл и изменить значение константы `THEME` на `home`. Затем перезаписать этот файл (права необходимые имеются).

Вопрос: есть ли универсальное решение этой задачи?
Или придется загружать файл как массив функцией `file()`, перебирать его в цикле и выискивать нужную константу регуляркой? Может есть более простое и изящное решение? Версия PHP на сервере 5.6.32

Comment: "универсальное" - вам нужно перезаписать N файлов? Или N констант в одном файле?

Comment: в одну строку решается например так `file-put-contents(файл, preg_replace("define('THEME', '[^']+');", "define('THEME', 'новое-значение');", file-get-contents(файл)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может стоит рассмотреть другие варианты хранения? например, в виде массива:

ваш файл настроек будет выглядеть, например, так:

```
<?php
    return  array (
       'TME_ID' => 15,
       'THEME' => 'auto',
       'TEMPLATE' => 'audi',
    );
```

записывать такой файл можно так:

```
$config = [
    'TME_ID' => 15,
    'THEME'  => "auto",.
    'TEMPLATE' => "audi",
];

$content = "<?php".PHP_EOL."\treturn\t".var_export($config, true);
file_put_contents("./config.php", $content);
```

а загружать и преобразовывать в константы так

```
$config = include "./config.php";

foreach($config as $k => $v){
    if(!defined($k)){
        define($k, $v);
    }
}
```

Потенциально будет у вас один файл конфига, и один файл - его загрзучик, как то так упрощенно

```
class Settings {

   static $cfg = null;

   public static function load(){
       static::$cfg = include "./config.php";
       foreach(static::$cfg as $k => $v){
          if(!defined($k)){
              define($k, $v);
          }
       }
   }

   public static function set($key, $value){
       static::$cfg[$key] = $value;
   }

   public static function save(){
       $content = "<?php".PHP_EOL."\treturn\t".var_export(static::$cfg, true);

       file_put_contents("./config.php", $content);
   }
} Settings::load();
```

подключите его и будете использовать, примерно  так

```
require_once "settings.class.php"

Settings::set('THEME', 'home');
Settings::save();
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Константы в php** не изменяются в рантайме. Ознакомтесь -[php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.php).
  Как вытекает из названия  - **`константа`** - это переменная, которая не меняет (и не должна) своего значения в процессе выполнения скрипта. При этом каждый, кто работает с данным приложением чётко уверен в неизменности значения константы. Это её суть. И если в процессе обработки возникает необходимость перезаписи её значения, значит вы выбрали **неверный** алгоритм работы вашего приложения.

Для реализации поведения, необходимого вам, используйте **базу данных**. Сохраняйте значение темы в базе данных и проверяйте/изменяйте сколько угодно раз в течении работы приложения. Если не используете сервер БД, можете оперировать [SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/what-is-sqlite/)

Если же вам комфортно работать с файловой системой - переместите константы, которые могут требовать изменений, в массив. Далее создавайте файл, в него записывайте [serrialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) массив значений; при необходимости  [unserrialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), обрабатывайте их и снова перезаписывайте .

Comment: речь ведь не идет об изменении значения константы в рантайм, а об изменении значения в конфиге, основанном на применении констант.

Comment: @ teran Мой ответ опирается на мысль, что изменяемый файл конфига является частью того рантайма, в котором он собственно, переписывается. Хотя вопрос явно на это не указывает, он не утверждает и обратного. Я бы лично не хотел столкнуться с сайтом (как разработчик), где  по ходу константы могут менять свои значения =)