# Не могу перезаписать в файле значение внутри многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть файл **configs.php** в котором хранится многомерный массив с данными, например:

```
<?php
class configs {
    public static $array = [
        ['subarray0','Heading 0',['0-0','0-1']], // configs::$array[0] =>
        ['subarray1','Heading 1',['1-0','1-1']] // configs::$array[1] =>
    ];
}
?>
```

И есть например файл **main.php** который перезаписывает данные в файле *configs.php*:

```
<?php
$fileToBeOverwritten = __DIR__ .'/configs.php';
require_once $fileToBeOverwritten;
$currentSubarray = configs::$array[1]; // берем текущий подмассив с индексом 1 с общего массива $array
configs::$array[1][1] = 'New Heading 1'; // меняем 'Heading 1' на 'New Heading 1'
$changedSubarray = configs::$array[1]; // определяем изменённый подмассив
$currentFileSource = file_get_contents($fileToBeOverwritten); // берем текущий код configs.php
$changedFileSource = str_replace($currentSubarray,$changedSubarray,$currentFileSource); // заменяем в коде файла текущий подмассив изменённым подмассивом
file_put_contents($fileToBeOverwritten,$changedFileSource); // перезаписываем изменённый код файла
?>
```

В данном случае все работает как и требуется.

Но вот когда пытаюсь в подмассиве `configs::$array[1]` перезаписать не строку `'Heading 1'` а какое то значение внутри вложенного массива `['1-0','1-1']` тогда не срабатывает.

Т.е. вот такой код

```
...
$currentSubarray = configs::$array[1];
configs::$array[1][2][0] = 'New 1-0'; // берём в подмассиве с индексом 1 третий элемент, который является вложенным массивом и пытаемся поменять в нем значение первого элемента
$changedSubarray = configs::$array[1];
...
```

не перезаписывает значение `'1-0'` новым значением `'New 1-0'`

В чем загвоздка?

Comment: загвоздка в том, что так вообще не надо делать

Comment: если вам прям нужно хранить массив в файле - используйте json или сериализацию и переписывайте его целиком. А глядя на то, что вы тут придумали - волосы в неожиданных местах дыбом встают

Comment: вот недавно был вопрос из этой области https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759979/223826 если уж перезаписывать значения непосредственно пхп, то через `var_export`.

Comment: @teran решение с `var_export` уже видел, но насколько понял оно подходит лишь если в файле только один массив, потому что $content начинается с `<?php` А у меня в файле конфигураций несколько разных массивов и нужно вносить изменение только в какой то один. И пока что просто не нашел другого решения

Comment: @stckvrw ключевой фразой ответа на который я сослался выше было "возможно, вам стоит изменить формат хранения". То что написано у вас, работать не будет, а если чудом заработает то создаст вам кучу проблем, т.к. это даже костылем назвать сложно. Не надо пытаться парсить и менять пхп код, который потом вы будете использовать. В вашем варианте в файле меняется все вхождения соответствующих строк, ни о какой перезаписи значения массива речи не идет, тем более какого то конкретного.

Comment: Это вы уже перегибаете палицу. Как видно с моего вопроса перезаписать `'Heading 1'` я могу без проблем. Проблема опять же с перезаписью вложенного массива. Конечно, в таком случае нужно искать другое решение. К стати, по вашей же ссылке @Lexx918 советует в комменте такой же способ, только preg_replace вместо str_replace. Я не сторонник этого способа, я просто другого пока не вижу

Comment: а почему не инклюднуть файл, переформировать массив, как надо, и не сохранить обратно через var_export ? не шедевр, но быстро и сердито

Comment: Есть же миллион нормальных форматов - yml, xml, json. В БД в конце концов.

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1809286/3208225) пишут что достаточно хранить в виде public static php variables. Интересует хранение в файле, а не в БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загвоздка в том, что вы неправильно заменяете значения в строке. Функция `str_replace` принимает в качестве аргументов строки или массивы строк. Значения, которые не являются строками, например такие, как ваш вложенный массив, приводятся к строкам (получается мы ищем строку 'Array'). В результате значение в массиве вы поменяли, но замена в строке отработала не так как вы надеялись.

В любом случае `str_replace` это не дело, ведь может оказаться, что значения в разных массивах будут одинаковые, и тогда замена отработает неправильно даже для строк.

А правильно будет перезаписать весь файл configs.php целиком:

```
$changedFileSource = '<?php

class configs {
    public static $array = ' . var_export($changedConfigs, true) . ';
 }
';
file_put_contents($fileToBeOverwritten, $changedFileSource);
```

Но вообще генерировать такой код, возможно, не самая хорошая идея и лучше воспользоваться возможностью вернуть значение из подключаемого файла:

```
<?php
// configs.php

return [
    ['subarray0','Heading 0',['0-0','0-1']],
    // ...
];
```

И подключать так:

```
<?php
// main.php

$configs = require __DIR__ . '/configs.php';
```

Тогда генерировать придётся только дескриптор `<?php`, `return` и точку с запятой `;`.

Comment: @stckvrw А почему вы думаете, что не работает? Работает. Только вы там точку с запятой забыли.