# Запись элемента в массив с изменением файла

Tags: php, массивы, запись

Имеется файл настроек config.php. Настройки хранятся в ассоциативном массиве. Нужно, чтобы можно было из админки перезаписывать значения ключей в массиве. То есть чтобы они и в файле перезаписывались. Форму и обработчик я уже написал. Данные все приходят. На экран вывести могу, а записать в файл нет. Через fwrite() тупо стирает все и записывает одну строку.
Вот config.php:

```
$config = array(
 'description' => 'Введите описание!',
 'keywords' => 'ключевые слова',
 'blog_name' => 'Название сайта',
 'template' => 'briton',
 'db' => array(
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'user' => 'root',
     'password' => '',
     'basename' => 'armor' 
    )
);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: еще про `var_export` почитать стоит

Comment: вопрос по теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759957/223826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Подробней о [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php).**

```
$config = array(
    'description' => 'Введите описание!',
    'keywords' => 'ключевые слова',
    'blog_name' => 'Название сайта',
    'template' => 'briton',
    'db' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'basename' => 'armor'
    )
);

$contents = var_export($config, true); // Если передано и значение равно TRUE, var_export() вернет представление переменной вместо его вывода.

file_put_contents('config.php', "<?php\n return {$contents};\n");
```

**Результат в `config.php`:**

```html
<?php
     return array (
      'description' => 'Введите описание!',
      'keywords' => 'ключевые слова',
      'blog_name' => 'Название сайта',
      'template' => 'briton',
      'db' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'basename' => 'armor',
      ),
    );
```

---

**UPDATE** Чтобы просто перезаписать строку.

```
$for_edit = "template";               // Ищем ключ который нужно заменить
$what = "'template' => 'my_own',\n";  // А тут делаем строку из ключа и нового значения этого ключа
$fopen = @file("config.php");  

foreach ($fopen as $key => $value) {
    if (substr_count($value,$for_edit)) {     
        array_splice($fopen, $key, 1, $what); // Если нашли совпадение, то заменяем
    }
    $f = fopen("config.php", "w"); // Перезаписали в файл
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fopen); $i++) {
        fwrite($f, $fopen[$i]);
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Вывести массив я могу, а как перезаписать одно из значений в сам файл?Скажем, получаем из _POST значение "Название сайта 2" и меняем Название сайта на Название сайта 2 чтобы оно в самом файле переписалось

Comment: @Иван, Обновил.

Comment: От души спасибо, Уважаемый! Все прекрасно работает! Пойду думать теперь, как менять несколько параметров. Контактенация не спасает, надо курить мануалы.

Comment: @Иван, пользуйтесь на здоровье:))